# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Nodelist> has no method "submit" in chrome

Tags: java, javascript, forms

I am submitting form through ajax, I get the above error. It works only in Firefox but not in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

Here is my form submission:

```
document.forms.loginPage.action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/colAuth?pAct=login";
document.forms.loginPage.submit();
```

Can any one tel me a solution?

Comment: Question is tagged "javascript", "jquery", "forms". `"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/colAuth?pAct=login";` is some server-side language. What is actually served to the browser?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: it seems to be Java, so I added that tag. But it still leaves the question incomplete as you said: we need to see the HTML that the browser actually gets server. OP: please add this HTML or your question will end up unanswered (and probably closed due to being too localized).

Comment: What is the HTML for how the `loginPage` form is defined?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, aha java. Does that automatically make it JSP?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement with jquery,

```
$("#formid").submit();
```

Or by link with jquery,

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#formid').submit();">submit</a>
```